# Check for regional language in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a scenario where i have to check if message contains any regional language then the type should be "2" or if it contains English(can contains special char, digits) language then the type should be "0".

I have tried using

```
for (char c: messages.get(0).message().toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == 
                     Character.UnicodeBlock.DEVANAGARI) {
                isHindi = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

but in java it checks for each specific language.

I want to write generalise code for that.
Thanks

Comment: You for look for any unicode > 127

Comment: what do you mean by saying "special characters"? You should more clarify your question. What are regional languages??

Answer (score 1):

English is all ASCII so you can do

```
if (c > 127 && Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) // non English letter or digit.
```

Comment: what if there is also special characters ? @Peter Lawrey

Comment: @ManishMehta It depends on whether you want to treat special characters as regional. You could just check for `c > 127`

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey  Thanks, it helped me

Comment: `"Ich glaube nicht, dass das funktioniert"`, is a `String` saying I don't believe that this will work, in German. There is no character based test that will reveal that this string is not English…

Comment: @Holger and empty string is much the same in any language. A word dictionary could help detect non English words though you can have words in English not in the dictionary eg abbreviations or place names.

Answer (score 1):

Let's convert it into a method, it serves better.

```
class IndianTest {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String x = "यर";
        if (textContainsIndian(x)) {
            System.out.println("indian");
        } else if (isEnglish(x)) {
            System.out.println("english");
        } else
            System.out.println("another language");

    }

    public static boolean textContainsIndian(String text) {
        for (char charac : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(charac) == Character.UnicodeBlock.DEVANAGARI) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isEnglish(String name) {
        return name.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
    }
}
```

Now, you can modify the code as your purpose.

Comment: but in that case i need to check for all languages, so many of if conditions will be there, is there any short  and emphasise solution for this?

Comment: @ManishMehta your question is not clear. Do you expect to specify whole languages of countries?

Comment: I have simple question for english(can contain digit and special char) the type will be 0 and for other regional language the type will 2

Comment: @ManishMehta what are the special characters??

Comment: @ snr  All the possible special characters